# How to override ActiveRecord method for one Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to override, `last` method, for my class `Calculations`.

```
# app/models/calculations.rb
class Calculations < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.last
    console.info "Run my custom Calculations.last"
    order(:custom_field).limit(1).last
  end
end

1.9.3-p194 :001 > Calculations.last
custom last
Calculations Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `calculations`.* FROM `calculations` ORDER BY calculations.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Calculations date: "2016-01-13", direction: "order", ...>

1.9.3-p194 :003 > Calculations.where(nil).last
Calculations Load (45.1ms)  SELECT `calculations`.* FROM `calculations` ORDER BY `calculations`.`` DESC LIMIT 1
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'calculations.' in 'order clause': SELECT  `calculations`.* FROM `calculations`  ORDER BY `calculations`.`` DESC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'calculations.' in 'order clause': SELECT  `calculations`.* FROM `calculations`  ORDER BY `calculations`.`` DESC LIMIT 1
```

First example called custom method.
Second called, AR original method.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Have you reloaded your console ?

Comment: the problem is : ORDER BY `calculations`.`` If no order clause is specified with `last` it uses the primary key (aka id). It looks like you don't have any id column here

Comment: It's true. This model is view for 3 tables. And Calculations cannot has id.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have overridden `.last` for the `Calculations` class, but in your second line you are calling `.last` on `Calculations::ActiveRecord_Relation` (returned by the where clause), which is not the one you defined. I am not sure how clean this is, but it should work (no need to override `.last` in your class too):

```
class Calculations < ActiveRecord::Base
  class ActiveRecord_Relation
    def self.last
      console.info "Run my custom Calculations.last"
      order(:custom_field).limit(1).last
    end
  end
end
```

Additional point. If you have no special reasons to use a plural name for your model, consider changing it to singular, which is the rails convention.

Comment: Thank you. Where do I can to read about reasons to making plural name? In my case Calculations is view table of Orders, Accounts and Payments, with some calcs.

Comment: Strange, I tested it and it worked for me. On ActiveRecord naming conventions, you can have a look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record)

Comment: May be because I use rails 3 in this project.

Answer (score 0):

To override ::last for Calculations you could do:

```
class Calculations < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.last
    puts "OVERRIDING"
    super
  end
end
```

although I wouldn't recommend it.

For what you are doing it looks like a scope might work

```
scope :last_record, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) }
```

Comment: I know solution with scope. I can use default_scope. But I want know how to override AR last method. You are only include super. But it doesn't work if I call Calculations.where(nil).last. In this case will called clear AR.last without puts "OVERRIDING"